# URL rewrite module IIS - redirecting act differently when I change rule name

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

Recently I have been facing very strange issue with IIS rewrite module. So, I am trying redirect one of URL to a desired URL.

```
<rule name="Redirect to merchant dashboard login page" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="*://*/*/login*" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://dev.mydomain.com/apply/{C:3}/login" />
</rule>
```

In IIS manager this rule look like this:

[image]

also, just for the reference, in IIS manager there is option to test the pattern with my URL. So I give a screenshot of it how it look like:

[image]

As you can see, from the above picture my pattern extracting backreference correctly. So, when I hit a URL which match with this pattern I am expecting it should redirect me to the URL stated in IIS redirect URL part. However, when I hit a URL for example "https://dev.mydomain.com/rms/login" it append lots of "apply" word to the redirected URL which is so weird. Like the image below:

[image]

while debugging the issue from the browser I have found that when I hit the URL it hit the url multiple times and each time it add the backreference {c:3} to the redirected URL as a result it does not work.

What is so strange is the when I just change the rule name "Redirect to merchant dashboard login page" to "Redirect to merchant dashboard signup page" it works perfectly, which is - it redirect me to my expected URL [https://circle.dev-youlend.com/apply/{C:3}/login](https://circle.dev-youlend.com/apply/%7BC:3%7D/login)

I am not understanding how can a change in Rule name make it working, how can I make it working even when I change the rule name?

Comment: The regular expression dialog is less useful, as the actual runtime value of `CACHE_URL` might not be always as you wished. So FRT should be used to debug your rewrite rules, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Besides, always use privacy mode of your web browser to open new tabs and test rewrite rules, as in that way the redirections are not cached and you can see the correct results.

Comment: In my test, it can redirect to correct URL and work well. So consider that some other modules affect the redirection. Please use failed request tracing to check how rewrite module modify the URL.